# Link Tracker C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, download, browser

I am creating a download manager, and I need to be able to find out what link was clicked on (so my download manager can begin downloading the file), and also need to be able to **stop** the browser from launching its default download manager.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this, or know of any links to articles/tutorials/related docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way is to write a pluggin for IE which is done through Browser Helper Objects and that is unmanaged C++. Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(VS.85).aspx